.NET 8 Ldap Authenticate Empty LdapException.ServerErrorMessage on Linux
When I use LDAP on windows, I can correctly obtain the Server ErrorMessage to suppress the error message. But ServerErrorMessage results on Linux are all empty
And i found the same problem on this issue
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/70210
This is my function to call the Ldap Authenticate
public void Authenticate(string username, string password)
{
    var ldapUsername = $"{_ldapDomain}\\{username}";
    var ldapPassword = password;

    using var connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(_ldapServer, _ldapPort));

    connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
    connection.Credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ldapUsername, ldapPassword);
    connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;


    try
    {
        connection.Bind();
    }
    catch (LdapException ex)
    {
        var message = ex.ErrorCode switch
        {
            49 => ex.ServerErrorMessage switch
            {
                string s when s.Contains("data 525") => "User not found. Please check your username.",
                string s when s.Contains("data 52e") => "AD authentication failed. Please check your username and password.",
                string s when s.Contains("data 530") => "Login not permitted at this time. Please contact your administrator.",
                string s when s.Contains("data 531") => "Login not permitted from this workstation. Please contact your administrator.",
                string s when s.Contains("data 532") => "Password expired. Please update your password.",
                string s when s.Contains("data 533") => "Account disabled. Please contact your administrator.",
                string s when s.Contains("data 534") => "Login requires a secure connection. Please ensure you are using a secure connection and try again.",
                string s when s.Contains("data 701") => "Account expired. Please contact your administrator.",
                string s when s.Contains("data 773") => "Password must be reset. Please update your password.",
                string s when s.Contains("data 775") => "Your AD account is locked. Please try again later.",
                _ => $"Authentication failed, please check your username and password, or contact support."
            },
            _ => "LDAP server internal error: please contact support.",
        };
        throw new AuthenticationException(message, ex);
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}


Hi, and welcome to Stackoverflow! I think you'll have to clarify your question. I guess that you are running the client on Linux, and the LDAP server you are talking to is an Active Directory. You are catching every single exception, but handling only one. Are you sure you get error 49 back? Add the result of Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); to your question (please do not post the result in the comments).

Because I only want to catch user validation errors but I need detailed errors within 49

Sure, but the code does not do what we want, there is a problem with it that we are trying to find together. Let's first validate the assumptions by adding details about the exception object, starting with the error code you actually get.

I changed the package to Novell.Directory.Ldap, and it works on Linux. Thanks.

I changed the package to Novell.Directory.Ldap, and it works on Linux.
